# How to load images into a page using a php file but wait for all images load before displaying

Tags: php

This is the minimum code in order to demonstrate the effect.

https://replit.com/@computinginschools/imageload#index.php

This is a simple php file which loads image using an external script, `image.php`, and displays them on the page. The reason I have done this on my live site is because the images are stored outside the `www` folder and I need the `image.php` script to access them. To make it easier I have just put everything under the webroot.

In this example, all the images are located in a folder called `images` next to `index.php`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image Load</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php 
      $images = glob('images/*.png');
      foreach($images as $image){
        echo('<img src="image.php?i='.urlencode($image).'" loading="lazy">');
      }
    ?> 
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the `image.php` file which loads the images.

```
<?php
  $path = urldecode($_GET['i']);

  if (file_exists($path)) {
    $extension = pathinfo($path)['extension'];
      header('Content-type:'.$extension);
      header('Cache-control:public, max-age=604800');
      header('Accept-ranges:bytes');
      header('Content-length:'.filesize($path));
      header('Last-Modified: '.date(DATE_RFC2822, filemtime($path)));
      header_remove('pragma');
      echo(file_get_contents($path));
  }
  else {
    echo("File not found: ".$file);
  }
?>
```

The script works fine to display the images however, the loading is often prolonged with all the images loading in a 'wave' as the `image.php` file renders them on the screen after `index.php` has loaded. The REPL is fast so this is not really noticeable, however, on my production site, this effect is quite pronounced.

I would like to know if there is a way of delaying the loading of the images in `index.php` until all the images rendered by `images.php` have loaded. My intention is to set the display attribute of the images to `none` by default and then, when the `index.php` document has loaded, apply an `appear` animation to all the images on the page to make them fade into view.

It would be even better if I could embed some kind of loading animation in the container for each image.

Please help?

Comment: The end desired result can be achieved with javascript. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+preload+images   .You could possible use the sleep function of php to maybe work, but I think this is better done with javascript. [link]https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php in your loop on index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't really be done in PHP; the slowdown is from the browser going through the HTML and loading all of the images. If you would like to hide the page until everything is loaded, then you can set the HTML `body` to `display: none`, and the use JavaScript to remove that once all of the images are loaded. This has to be done from JavaScript because there isn't really any way to check on the browser's status from PHP.

If you must do this from PHP, then you *can* have all of the images inline using base64 encoding, although this is just about the least efficient way of serving images, and will probably cause major slowdowns. The format to do so is like this:

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($image)); ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you - that's a really interesting way of handling it. I've currently done it by hiding the images and then adding an onload event to a clone of the image - I found it online and I've implemented it here...

https://replit.com/@computinginschools/imageload#index.php

If I were to wait and then display the whole page, how do I do a loading animation?

Comment: When I needed to do something similar, I used  a full page div with a centered Bootstrap spinner before the content, and then had another div with all of the content with `display: none;`. Once everything is loaded, I then hid the spinner and displayed the actual content.

Comment: Thank you - I've not used Bootstrap before but I think I've implemented something similar now : https://the.computing.cafe/. Now I sometimes notice that the page 'grows' as the hidden content loads (mainly the pictures) but I don't think I can prevent that?